# How to associate dictionnary keys with description using Flask

Tags: python, flask, translation

I am using Flask to build my web application.
I have a dictionnary with some key in it, unfortunatly these keys are not easily readable for a user. I'd like to display nicer name and a descriptions sentence for each keys.

The display of my keys is in jinja2 loop, iterating over the dictionnary.

My actual page:

```
key_1 : value_1
key_2 : value_2
```

The page I want to have:

```
Nice name for key1 (Description of the key1) : value_1
Nice name for key2 (Description of the key2) : value_2
```

I already look in flask-babel extension, but it does not seems to fit since the keys in jinja2 template will be displayed at runtime. Even if I am manually creating a .po file with all possible keys, I doubt it will correctly work.

I was thinking to use a database to make the correspondance, but I think it might not be the nicest way to do that

```
key_1 = { name : "Nice name for key1"
          description : "Nice description for key1"
         }
```

What do you think would be the best way of doing such correspondance ?

**EDIT:**
My keys are coming from a dictionnary passed to the template from flask. I dont think from where the dictionnary is coming is important.

So It looks like `return render_template(mypage.html, dictionnary=dictionnary)`

I am not really trying to translate my nice name and description in a first time, just make a link between the keys of the dictionnary and names and descriptions to display which are understandable to users. I though using flask-babel cause it first looks like a way of doing such links. Unfortunatly I think because my keys are generating at runtime with jinja2 it will not work.

```
{% for key,value dictionnary.iteritems()%}
<li> {{ key }}, {{value}} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Use babel/flask-babel if you want to translate your content in different languages.*

It isn't entirely clear for me what you're trying to achieve here.

1. Where do you get the keys from?
2. Do you want to translate your *nice name* and descriptions?

Although, if you are looking to convert some string like `'weight_of_the_sun'` to `'Weight of the sun'`, you could consider using [inflection](http://inflection.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Use [inflection.humanize](http://inflection.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#inflection.humanize)

```
import inflection

print(inflection.humanize('weight_of_the_sun'))
# Prints: Weight of the sun
```

Depending on what you want to do, some other function might work also.

**EDIT:** Don't bother looking into babel if you aren't translating anything.

I would recommend some structure like:

```
your_dict = {
    'key_1': {
        'name': "Whatever name",
        'value': Whatever value,
        'description': "Whatever description"
    }, ...
}
```

Use this like,

```
{% for key, struct in your_dict.iteritems() %}
  <li>{{ key }} {{ struct['name'] }} {{ struct['description'] }} {{ struct['value'] }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

**OR,**

```
your_list = [
    {
        'key': 'key_1',
        'name': "Whatever name",
        'value': Whatever value,
        'description': "Whatever description"
    }, ...
]
```

NOTE: I like this better because you can order a `list`.

Use this like,

```
{% for struct in your_list %}
  <li>{{ struct['key'] }} {{ struct['name'] }} {{ struct['description'] }} {{ struct['value'] }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I edited my post, hoping it will solve your interrogation. I do not really need to translate my nice name. You can see my purpose as nice name and descriptions being the translation of keys.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I think I will do as your exemple, following the dictionnary with the new field. I actually thought about that, just that I don't have these value in first place, so I will need to look in a database to retrieve them. Just thought this will be little bit ugly.

Comment: You can always make your query to the database cleaner, if that's not clean. If I knew more about what exactly you are trying to do, I could suggest how to make it cleaner.